# Javascript does not work in IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have tried everything, changed and stripped my code. A simple alert message just won't work in IE 7 and IE 8.

Here is my code

```
<html>
    <head>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            alert("hi");

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <form action="#" onSubmit="test(); return false;">
        <input type="image" class="button" src="img/button-en-send-now.jpg" value="Submit"  />
    </form>

</body>
```

I even tried it onsubmit and with a button. Of course I used a function for this. 
I also did my homework and searched the web first. I know there is this hack with the jssvr32 javascript.dll (or something like that). It doesn't work at all.

I changed my security properties to the lowest level possible, it doesn't work. I reloaded the page a thousand times, cleared the cache every time. Reinstalled every version of the browser, it DOES NOT work :(

Has anybody any clue and recent problems with it?

Edit: Here is the full code, but as I said, I've already tried several things and this is the code which should just alert a simple "hi". Which it doesn't do -.-

You can use this also this link: http://medienportfolio.bplaced.net/ftpzugriff/pump-guide-english.html

Comment: please give use the codes you are currently working on

Comment: I edited my Q. I'm absolutely no beginner or noob. I know what I'm doing, just have this in mind ^^

Comment: Have you checked that you havn't mistakenly disabled javascript in IE? [link](http://www.technipages.com/internet-explorer-7-enabledisable-javascript.html)

Comment: imho first check if your code is working under firefox or chrome? If yes, then start troubleshooting IE else start debugging your code..

Comment: I wish I would have been so stupid or it would have been that easy. It is activated. Does someone have IE7 / IE8 and can test my code/page? It also works in IE 5.5, IE6 and IE9... 

@Rishi Kalia: It works in FF and Chrome perfectly! There is not much to debbug, is it?

Comment: your `alert("hi");` works for me in IE7..

Comment: I can't explain it myself. I have Win7 on a 64bit machine. I'll explain a bit more: The page is for on of our clients who told us our script does not work. Often there is a quick solution or the client is wrong but I also have this bug/error whatsoever.

Comment: you need to be more specific about your problem, it's all right that you are no beginner or noob but how could someone help if you won't let them know the exact code that's giving problem..

Comment: In IE7 and IE8 the alert "hi" does not appear at all. Without any error message or anything else. If already this isn't showing up, why post all the other code which is not working, too?

Comment: Our Windows is always up to date, could this be a problem? I will have to test it at home, I guess. This is very frustrating and I can't help you more, so you can help me better, I'm afraid ._.

Comment: I am getting curious about this issue. You have my up-vote. Sadly, I have currently no IE at my desk, but might get hold of a notebook later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you, by chance, work on a domain or host that has an underscore in it? If yes, please be aware, that IE does not execute javascript on hosts with a underscore or any charcter that IE finds exotic. This also includes subdomains.

We had this problem with a subdomain/hostname where the machine was named customer_cms.domain.com.

Comment: Seems to be another problem, was the URL stated above is completely ok.

Comment: I renamed the file: http://medienportfolio.bplaced.net/ftpzugriff/pump.html - still not working. But thanks. And I tried it on 2 different servers.